# Ember ListBox Scroll when out of view port

Tags: jquery, ember.js, listbox, scroll

I have created a ListBox View and Controller in Ember.

I need to move by one up or down (scroll the ul correctly) when I got to en element which is out of view port.

I just need a ListBox keyboard driven.

```
Ember.ListBoxController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
    contentDidLoad: ((e) ->
        @set("selectedId", 0)
    ).observes('content.isLoaded')
    updateSelected: ( -> 
        id = @get("selectedId")

        length = @get("content.length")

        if id >= 0 and id < length
            @set "selected", (@toArray())[id] 
    ).observes "selectedId"
    actions: 
        select: (id) ->
            length = @get "content.length"

            if id >= 0 and id < length
                @set "selectedId", id
            selectNext: ->
            @send "select", (@get "selectedId") + 1
        selectPrev: ->
            @send "select", (@get "selectedId") - 1
```

And the view

```
Ember.ListBoxView = Ember.CollectionView.extend 
    tagName: "ul"
    contentBinding: "controller"
    classNames: ["list-box"]
    didInsertElement: ->
        @$().attr tabindex: 1
        @$().focus()
    keyDown: (e) ->
        e.preventDefault()
        if e.keyCode == 40
            @get("controller").send("selectNext")
        else if e.keyCode == 38
            @get("controller").send("selectPrev")
```

View Item (Actually I'm subclassing it and passing a template)

```
Ember.ListBoxItemView = Ember.View.extend
    tagName: "li"
    isActive: (->
        return @get("content.id") == @get("controller.selected.id")
    ).property("controller.selected")
    classNameBindings: ["isActive:active"]
```

Any Idea How could I achieve that?

I was thinking about using Ember.Evented and from select action of controller fire a trigger, catch it in the  view and using  jquery do some scrolling, but it seems too complicated and I think there will be much better Ember way.

I tried also to have outOfViewPort computed property on ListBoxItemView observing controller selected and in parent observer outOfViewPort for children and then scroll properly, but It didn't work at all.